# Remove rule from network security group

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

How can I remove a rule from a Network Security Group (classic) in Azure? There isn't any way to do this from the Portal, and I can't find a Powershell cmdlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "MyVNetSG" | Remove-AzureNetworkSecurityRule -Name WEB
```